# Linear Algebra - Rank and Nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm really stuck on this question don't really understand how to prove this:

**It says, for the given map verify that the rank-nullity theorem holds:**

$$
f: M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^3: \left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right) \mapsto (a-2b+c,b+d,a+c+2d)
$$

So I understand we have to prove the $\text{Im}(f)$ and $\text{Ker}(f)$, but how? Where do I start?

Thanks,
Reety.

Comment: Couldn't upload the picture because I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: You start with the definition of $\ker(f)$. Recall that the kernel is the set of all elements $s$ such that $f(s) = 0$ (the zero vector).

Comment: right so i let f(a,b,c,d)=0 but what do i do from there?

Comment: Once you did this, you get that certain things are zero. That is, $a-2b+c,b+d,a+c+2d$ are all zero. Now, the set of solutions of this, forms a vector space. You have to tell us what the dimension of this vector space is. To do this, solve the above equation until you get a set of "free" variables i.e. those whose value can be freely varied to give different solutions. For example, if $b+d = 0$, then $d$ depends on $b$, so cannot be free. Find out how many independent variables are there, this is the dimension of the kernel.

Comment: ok so we get a-2b+c=0, b+d=0 and a+c+2d=0; so therefore there are 3 independent variables since d is the same as -b, therefore the dim(ker(f)) is 3?

Comment: There are *not* three independent variables. Allow me to apologize, if it was my mistake. See, if $b+d=0$, then $d=-b$. So $a+c-2b=0$ and $a-2b+c = 0$, which are the same equation. Now, I claim that $a$ and $c$ are the only free variables, because once you fix these, then $2b = a+c$, so $b$ gets fixed, and $d = -b$, so $d$ gets fixed. So, *fixing $a,c$ allows us to fix all the variables*. Therefore, $a$ and $c$ are the free variables (see from the equations that there's no relation between $a$ and $c$). So the dimension of the kernel is $2$.

Comment: No need to apologise, thank you for being really helpful, I think I understand now, but would that be sufficient enough to prove that the ker(f) is 2? Or is there some other steps we have to show? And also how would I go about proving Im(f)? is the dim im(f) = 1 since f(x,0,0,0)=x so im(f) = R and therefore (surjective)

Comment: In case you are wondering why I have not replied for some time, I am writing an answer, since what I would like to say cannot fit in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigorously speaking, the kernel of $f$ is precisely those vectors which map to $0$ under $f$. This forms a vector space.

Now, of course if you are trying to find elements in the kernel, you equate these terms to $0$. We did that and got $a-2b+c = 0,b+d = 0, a+2d+c = 0$, right? Now, we simplified this, by just seeing how many "free" variables there are. This is how we think of free variables:

> If you fix these variables, then all the other variables get fixed, with the help of the equations. However, if you don't fix all of them, then you won't be able to fix all variable values.

For example, here, I had said that $a,c$ were the free variables. For example, if I tell you that $a=2,b=6$ , then from above you can say that $b = 4$ and $d = -4$, so all variables get fixed. However, if I only tell you that $c = 2$, you cannot fix the values of $a,b$ and $d$.

The dimension of any vector space is a measure of its freedom in that sense. How many parameters are there in this space? That is the question that must be asked.

By the way, noticing the number of free variables is *rigorous enough* to show the dimension is $2$. If you want, you can now give a basis for the kernel : fix $a=0,c=1$ and find $b,d$. Now, fix $a=1,c=0$ and find $b,d$. Find the matrices that have entries $a,b,c,d$ (there will be two of them, one for each case). These will form a basis for the kernel. So the kernel has dimension $2$.

For the image, something similar has to be done.

What is the image? Well, every vector of the form $(a-2b+c,b+d,a+2d+c)$. Let $x = a-2b+c,y=b+d,z = a-2d+c$. Play the same game:

> Given $x,y,z$, which are the "free" variables? How many variables must I fix, so that the others get fixed?

To see this, let us calculate $x+2y$. This is equal to $a-2b+c + 2b+2d = a+2d+c = z$. So, we got $x+2y = z$.

Now, this means that if I fix $x,y$ then $z$ gets fixed. So, if $x=1,y=2$, then $z=4$ (therefore, for example, something like $(1,2,17)$ won't be in the image, since here $z \neq x + 2y$).

You can also see that this is all we can do. Just fixing $x$ or $y$ gets us nowhere,. Experiment with $x,y,z$ to see that no more meaningful relations can be found.

So, the number of free variables, and hence the dimension of the image, is $2$. Again, if you really want to be rigorous, just do this : put $x=0,y=1$ and find $z$. Then, put $x=1,y=0$ and find $z$. Then, the vectors $(x,y,z)$ (there will be two of them, one for each case) form a basis for the image of $f$.

Therefore, the rank nullity theorem is verified, since $2+2 = 4$, which is equal to the dimension of the vector space of two dimensional square matrices, as asserted by the RN theorem.

So this is how you are "expected to proceed" as an approach to these simple questions. However, as you progress, you will learn tools that will help you simplify such equations and make calculations like the above more easier.

Comment: Thank you very much, very clear and concise! much appreciated.

Comment: Since you are happy, you may upvote and accept the answer. This is unless you are willing to wait for other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with matrices. Take the basis
$$
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$
of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then the matrix associated to $f$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
A standard Gaussian elimination yields
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The rank of the matrix is $3$, so this is the rank of $f$. The null space of this matrix is generated by the vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the kernel of $f$ is generated by the matrix having that vector as coordinate vector, that is,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}-2&-1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$